# How to read an unknown provider error in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

Currently there is an error in console as below,

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: userProvider <- user <- MainCtrl
```

My understanding per AngularJS docs, https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr, is this typically relates to dependency issues.

I'm not concerned about solving this specific error (already solved, or at least made it disappear by removing ng-controller directive from view), but **I want to understand** the syntax of the error provided by angular.

I see 3 basic parts (in above error) with arrows between them.

1. userProvider
2. user
3. MainCtrl

How might this direction be used in troubleshooting a future issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What it's saying is in your `MainCtrl` there is something being injected called `user`, it can't find this as it's looked for the `userProvider`